# Alternative to AssetSync gem for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

Recently, on my latest deploy to Heroku, I got a warning [advising not to use AssetSync](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/please-do-not-use-asset-sync).

```
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        You are using the `asset_sync` gem.
remote:        See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/please-do-not-use-asset-sync for more information.
```

The original problem we were trying to solve by using AssetSync was that we were getting a huge slug size caused by the large assets in our application. Out of the 300MB that Heroku allows us, we were probably using close to 230MB - even though our git repo is only around 80MB.

We solved this by using AssetSync to synchronise all our compiled assets to a S3 bucket to be served through Cloudfront. After AssetSync runs, we have a hook that deletes all the precompiled assets to reduce the slug size. Basically, the workflow during slug compilation looked like this:

1. Let Heroku precompile the assets
2. AssetSync syncs all compiled assets to S3
3. All local copies of the compiled assets are deleted

The linked article argues a few points on why it's bad and what to use instead.

> Using Asset Sync can cause failures. It is difficult to debug,
>   unnecessary, and adds extra complexity. Don’t use it. Instead, use a
>   CDN.
>
> [...]
>
> You should now use a CDN instead. Rather than
>   copying your assets over to S3 after they are precompiled, the CDN
>   grabs them from your website. Here are some reasons why that’s better.
>
> **Canonical assets**
>
> [...] It allows you to have single, authoritative places where you
>   store information. If you need to change that information, you only
>   need to change it in one place. [...] What happens if someone has a
>   failed deploy after assets get synced? What if someone modifies a file
>   in the S3 bucket? Instead of fixing one copy of assets, now you must
>   fix two.
>
> **Deploy determinism**
>
> If you’re debugging inside of a dyno with heroku run bash and you run
>   rake assets:precompile this doesn’t just modify your local copy. It
>   actually modifies the copy on S3 as well. [...] The sync part of
>   asset_sync can also fail if there’s a glitch in the network. What if
>   you only write part of a file, or only half of your assets are synced?
>   These things happen.

Although I agree with their points, the question remains: what's the recommended way to deploy a Heroku application that becomes huge when precompiled assets are stored in the slug?

Comment: did you figure out something here?

Answer (score -3):

The question is which assets files are making the slug huge?

By default, the Rails assets pipeline should only be used for small and limited internal assets (like JS, CSS, some logos, etc.).

It's not a great idea to store a huge amount of external or big files as Rails assets for many reasons aside the pipeline (like it's making your Git directory big in size too).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is also incorrect.